# ajax function is not populating the table in HTML from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have 2 files(editableTable.php and fetch.php) and for now I am only trying to populate values from database("request" table under "registration structure) into the HTML table. It is not adding to the table for now

My script(ajax function) in "editableTable.php"

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function fetch_request_data(){
  $,ajax({
    url: "fetch.php",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      for(var count=0; count<data.length; count++)
      {
        var html_data = '<tr><td>'+data[count].id+'</td>';
        html_data += '<td data-name="type" class="type" data-type="text" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].type+'</td>';
        html_data += '<td data-name="date" class="date" data-type="text" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].date+'</td>';
        html_data += '<td data-name="notes" class="notes" data-type="text" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].notes+'</td>';
        html_data += '<td data-name="status" class="status" data-type="select" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].status+'</td></tr>';
        $('#request_data').append(html_data);
      }
    }
  });
}

fetch_request_data();
```

});

Code in fetch.php

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registration");
$query = "SELECT * FROM request";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Is this a copy&paste of the original code? If so, then there's a typo in `fetch_request_data()` (which should be mentioned in the console of your browser): `$,ajax({ `

Comment: Ya, I am trying to create an editable table and I am not experienced in Web Development. I am calling the fetch_request_data() function inside script and I did not get where the typo is. Please tell me:)

Comment: Is the post success actually called or any error in the console? You could use the .error() method for error handling

Comment: Like Andreas mentioned, there's a typo `$,ajax` should not have a coma, it should be `$.ajax`

Comment: No error, only showing the table headers without any data from database

Comment: Thank you for both of you. Now it worked:)

Comment: The first step if some script _"isn't working"_ -> check for errors in the console. This typo would have been really obvious and easy to find from the error in the console.